# Why does an undef value become a valid array reference in Perl?

Tags: perl

In perl 5.8.5, if I do the following, I don't get an error:

```
use strict;

my $a = undef;
foreach my $el (@$a) {
  ...whatever
}
```

What's going on here?  Printing out the output of `ref($a)` shows that `$a` changes to become a valid array reference at some point.  But I never explicitly set `$a` to anything.

Seems kind of odd that the contents of a variable could change without me doing anything.

Thoughts, anyone?

EDIT: Yes, I know all about auto-vivification.  I always thought that there had to be a assignment somewhere along the way to trigger it, not just a reference.

Comment: This is perl. Oddity is fine, because it's odd.

Comment: I don't think it's odd, just a convenience to save some declarations.

Comment: @Stefano: why bother checking Perl questions only to troll? It's tedious...

Comment: Telemachus: Python programmers think that there is always only one true way for every situation.

Comment: @Alexandr: Yes, I'm aware of the philosophy that "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it." But is the One True Way to handle questions about Perl `troll(post)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read [Uri Guttman's article on autovivification](http://www.perlarchive.com/___TLC/7026.shtml).

There is nothing odd about it once you know about it and saves a lot of awkwardness.

> Perl first evaluates a dereference expression and sees that the current reference value is undefined. It notes the type of dereference (scalar, array or hash) and allocates an anonymous reference of that type. Perl then stores that new reference value where the undefined value was stored. Then the dereference operation in progress is continued. If you do a nested dereference expression, then each level from top to bottom can cause its own autovivication.

Comment: Followup question. Why doesn't this auto-vivify: `my $a; my @x = @$a`?

Comment: @FM: in general, things that are only reading from a dereference won't autovivify, while things that may modify what's dereferenced do.
The for loop is an example of something that may modify (since $el is aliased into the array and the array may be changed through it).  This is only a loose rule, though; there are some rough edges.

Comment: be careful of cases with a subscript, even when just reading from them, autovivication will likely take place

Answer (score 16):

[Auto-vivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) is the word. From the link:

> Autovivification is a distinguishing feature of the Perl programming
>   language involving the dynamic
>   creation of data structures.
>   Autovivification is the automatic
>   creation of a variable reference when
>   an undefined value is dereferenced. In
>   other words, Perl autovivification
>   allows a programmer to refer to a
>   structured variable, and arbitrary
>   sub-elements of that structured
>   variable, without expressly declaring
>   the existence of the variable and its
>   complete structure beforehand.
>
> In
>   contrast, other programming languages
>   either: 1) require a programmer to
>   expressly declare an entire variable
>   structure before using or referring to
>   any part of it; or 2) require a
>   programmer to declare a part of a
>   variable structure before referring to
>   any part of it; or 3) create an
>   assignment to a part of a variable
>   before referring, assigning to or
>   composing an expression that refers to
>   any part of it.
>
> Perl autovivication can be contrasted against languages such as Python, PHP, Ruby, JavaScript and all the C style languages.

Auto-vivification can be disabled with [`no autovivification;`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autovivification)

Comment: I kept refreshing this page to see the answer cause I was curious. Wow, Perl really IS odd :)

Comment: This is Perl's virtue of DWIM (Do what I mean).

Comment: ... unless it bites you when you doesn't like it.

Comment: FYI, you can disable autoviv with http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autovivification

Comment: Thanks, daotoad. I have put that into the answer itself.