# Why does $foo->{bar} autovivify but %$foo doesn't?

Tags: perl, reference, autovivification

I have the following code:

```
$headers;
some_sub( %$headers );
```

When I call `some_sub` I get an error:

> Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at ...

But similar code does not produce an error:

```
$headers->{ x };
```

Why doesn't autovivification work the same way in the first example as it does in the second?

**UPD**

I noted by **@ThisSuitIsBlackNot**. I really ask:

> why my $h; $h->{foo} works and my $h; %$h doesn't

**UPD**
The real code:

```
my $email =  Email::Simple->create(
    header =>  [
        To             =>  $address,
        From           =>  $cnf->{ from },
        Subject        =>  $subject,
        'Content-Type' =>  'text/html; charset="utf8"',
        %$headers,
    ],
    body => $body
);
```

Comment: Well, what is the error message saying?  `Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference...` What does that mean? What does that tell you about `$headers`?

Comment: Is that code complete?  If so, `$headers` has `undef` as its value and you can't dereference the 'hash' that it doesn't reference.  You should be using `use strict; use warnings;` and `my $headers;` at minimum.  You could consider `my $headers = { };` too.  What did your searching with a term such as 'perl autovivification' return?  I used Google and got a number of useful looking articles to follow — Wikipedia, Perl Maven, Perl Monks.  Of those, [Explaining Autovivification](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=691557) seems most apposite.

Comment: That doesn't produce that error. Could you provide a complete example?

Comment: The `%$headers` has nothing to do with autovivification.  It merely attempts to _dereference_ the scalar variable `$headers`, into a hash. With `use strict` in effect it prints that message, but without it it only complains about _uninitialized value_.

Comment: I *think* you're really asking why `my $h; $h->{foo}` works and `my $h; %$h` doesn't. I like [ysth's explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643717/why-does-an-undef-value-become-a-valid-array-reference-in-perl#comment1514904_1643894): "in general, things that are only reading from a dereference won't autovivify, while things that may modify what's dereferenced do. The for loop is an example of something that may modify (since $el is aliased into the array and the array may be changed through it). This is only a loose rule, though; there are some rough edges."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot your commets are very usefull. I will award you on some your answers on last day of hats celebration! I can not award on comments (

Comment: Thanks for the update, this explains it (see my answer).

Comment: @EugenKonkov Please don't do that, I'd rather earn my imaginary internet points on merit alone :) This was a really interesting question, thanks for posting it!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: In any case I am planning to earn my points too: the `Philantropist` hat. So you will be my victim :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**   Code added to the question demostrates why autovivification doesn't happen.

**Short**   Your sub takes a list (hash) which has an anonymous array as an element – and `%$headers` is buried in that array. It is the *anon array*
that is the scalar aliased to, thus there is no requirement for `%$headers` to be modifiable. Thus no autovivification happens, and you get the fatal runtime error described below, as dereferencing is attempted on an undefined reference.

---

A `%$ref` autovivifies when used in *lvalue context*. This may happen in a sub call, see below.

The error you show is due to the use of an undefined reference. For example, the statement

```
my %hash = %{ $ref };
```

attempts to copy a hash from the memory location stored in `$ref` and assign it to `%hash`. The symbol `%hash` is created at compile time, but if no hash is found at `$ref` or if there is nothing in `$ref`, we get an error.  No autovivification happens here. With `use strict` in effect

```
perl -wE'use strict; my $h; my %h = %$h; say $h'
```

this throws the fatal runtime error

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at -e line 1.
```

When `eval`-ed to survive that

```
perl -wE'use strict; my $h; my %h = eval { %$h }; say $h; say "hi"'
```

it prints a warning about "*uninitialized value*", an empty line, and then `hi`.  No hash.

However, when used as an argument in a subroutine call it autovivifies

```
perl -wE'use strict; sub tt { 1 }; my $h; tt( %$h ); say $h'
```

as this prints the line `HASH(0x257cd48)`, without warnings or errors.

The autovivification happens when a dereferenced object is used in *lvalue context*, which means that it needs to be modifiable.  In a subroutine call the reason for this is that arguments to a function are aliased in `@_` so it must be possible to modify them. The same aliasing need makes it happen in a `foreach` loop, while `keys` resets the hash iterator. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419618/perl-vivification-question-while-dereferencing-undefined-array-reference) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206836/why-does-perl-autovivify-in-this-case) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029084/why-does-autovivification-occur-with-keys-and-not/35031218#35031218).

Thanks to [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) for explanation and links.

In your case the `%$ref` is passed as an element of an anonymous array, and is thus not aliased (the arrayref itself is). So autovivication does not kick in and you get that error.

---

On *autovivification* from [perlglossary](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#A)

> In Perl, storage locations (lvalues) spontaneously generate themselves as needed, including the creation of any hard reference values to point to the next level of storage. The assignment `$a[5][5][5][5][5] = "quintet"` potentially creates five scalar storage locations, plus four references (in the first four scalar locations) pointing to four new anonymous arrays (to hold the last four scalar locations). But the point of autovivification is that you don’t have to worry about it.

Also see, for example, an [article from Effective Perler](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/)

Comment: Actually, `%$foo` *does* trigger autovivification, *if* used in an l-value context: `perl -Mstrict -MDevel::Peek -wE'my $h; 1 for %$h; Dump $h'` (the `SV = PVHV` indicates that it's a hashref)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot At the risk of bothering you -- your _if_ above is critical.  Of course it comes up when assigned to, and it does when queried for keys as in mob's answer (even without a debugger).  But I don't see that it actually gets to that when it is only dereferenced into a hash. Updated.

Comment: The autovivification rules aren't really consistent (e.g. it doesn't make sense that `exists` would autovivify, but it does), but the best explanation I've seen is that in general, autovivification kicks in when the dereferenced thing could be modified (e.g. in an assignment, a `foreach` loop, arguments to a sub, etc). See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6419618), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35031218) to a related question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you, added this.

Comment: @zdim `>So autovivication does not kick in and you get that error.` :in %$h case it seems if it behaves as `noop` it will be more handy

Answer (score 5):

`%$hash` absolutely does autovivify when passed to a sub.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE'my $foo; say $foo // "undef"'
undef

$ perl -Mstrict -wE'sub f { } my $bar; f(%$bar); say $bar // "undef"'
HASH(0x10b50e0)
```

The error message comes from something else going on in `some_sub`, perhaps an improper assignment from `@_`.

Comment: "`%$hash` absolutely does autovivify when passed to a function (user or builtin)" True for some operators (e.g. `keys`), but not others (e.g. `length`).